# Ambiguous method signature on NULL value

Tags: apex, null, polymorphism, method-invocation

I know that all primitive types are objects and can be *null* in Apex

But is there a way to handle the *null* value when doing polymorphism **?**

```
public class myClass{
    public myClass(String name){
        // handle input
    }

    public myClass(Integer num){
        // handle input
    }
}

new myClass(null);
```

I am getting the error below when trying to instantiate my class with a *null* value

[image: Error on SFDevConsole]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The compiler cannot figure out which method to call here in the anonymous window because you are calling with 'null' explicitly vs having a variable type which it can use to figure out what you want. So, for example this code would work just fine:

```
String test = null;
new myClass(test);
```

Or, you could do:

```
new myClass((String)null);
```

In both cases we are providing the compiler with the information it needs to figure out which method to call.

Comment: +1, but it's not not necessary to assign null to a variable when declaring it, as the default value is null. This just wastes CPU time. Welcome to SFSE!

Comment: You can drop the assignment altogether from your first example. Declared variables are null until assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Matt for this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/164197/41226)

For me I handled that case like this, because I needed to be able to call *myClass* with an untyped *null*

```
public class myClass{
    public myClass(Object obj){
        if(obj == null){
            // handle input null
        }else if(obj instanceof String){
            // handle input String
        }else if (obj instanceof Integer){
            // handle input Integer
        }else {
            throw new myClassParamException('Error myClass handles only String or integer type');
        }

    }
}

public class myClassParamException extends Exception {}


new myClass(null);  // No error
```